# combinatorical description of classifying map for principal $G$-bundle over Delta set

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, classifying-spaces

Let $X$ be topological realization of a (finite) [Delta set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_set), $G$ a finite group and $p: P \to X$ a principal $G$-bundle. It's standard that the isom' classes of such principal $G$-bundles are classified by an (up to homotopy unique) classifying space $BG$, which posses also a model as a Delta set: see eg A. Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" page 89 for concrete construction.

That means that there exist a functorially compatible
bijection

$$C:[X, BG]_{\text{Htpy}} \to \text{PrinBun}_G(X)/ \sim, \ \
[f] \mapsto f^{*}U  $$

given explicitly by pulling back the universal
bundle $U: EG \to BG$ along a homotopy a map $f: X \to BG$
representing it's homotopy class $[f]$.
This raises the natural question if that's possible to
write in explicit terms the map in the other direction, the
"classifying map", namely
for any $p: P \to X$ a principal $G$-bundle, can we
construct a map $f_p:X \to BG$ whose pullback $f_p^*U$
of universal bundle is isomorphic to $p$ explicitly?

At first glace one obstruction for finding such map is that $BG$ is only unique up to a homotopy class therefore there exist several models of $BG$ giving homotopically the same object.
Nevertheless there exist two "distinguished" ways to construct
a model of $BG$, one directly as topological space, the
*"Milnor Construction"* (can be found eg Husemoeller's
"Fiber Bundles", p 54), the other firstly on simplicial level, the
*bar construction* (eg in Hatcher's AT. p 89), then passing to realization.

So one might pose the question about explicit for explicit construction *after* having fixed a concrete model for $BG$.

Husemoeller's book (Thm. 12.2, p 57) - is working with
Milnor's model of $EG$ and $BG$ -the explicit construction
of the classfying map is based on countable partition of unity
and works for numerable principal $G$-bundles over
paracompact base spaces $X$.

So using analytic methods it's possible to write down this map explicitly up to finding the partition of unity.

My question is if it's also possible to write down the classifying map purely combinatorically  or simplicially:  Assume that our base space $X$ is
a Delta set, and in following we work with Delta set model of $EG$ and $BG$
from Hatcher book. Hatcher's bar model of $BG$ is a Delta set with
$n$-simplices $[g_1 | g_2 |... |g_n]$ with boundaries $[g_1 | ... | g_i g_{i+1} | ... |g_n]$.

Is it possible to describe explicitly the
classifying map associated to a principal $G$-bundle
$p:P \to X$  map $f_p:X \to BG$ combinatorically?

Here an approach looking promissing but contains hurdles
I not know how to overcome:

Let $p: P \to X$ be a principal $G$-bundle with base
Delta set $X$. Let $X_0$ be the
set of vertices, and $X_1$ the set of $1$-simplices -
the "edges" - of Delta set $X$. If we could find a
covering family $(U_v)_{v \in X_0}$ of open connected
$U_v \subset X$ over which $p$ trivialize
$P_{\vert{U_v}} \cong U_v \times G$ parametrized by vertices
$X_0$ satisfying:

-vertex $v \in X_0$ lies in exactly one open set $U_v$
-every edge $e_{vw}$ with vertices $v$ and $w$ (note: there might be several edges with identical vertices) lies in
$U_v \cup U_w$ for unique pair of vertices $v,w \in X_0$
and the intersection $e_{vw} \cap U_v 
\cap U_w$  is isomorphic to an open interval

If such covering family $(U_v)_{v \in X_0}$ exists, then
we can try to construct the classifying map as follows:

This covering family $(U_v)_{v \in X_0}$  would give us
a cocycle $(g_{vw}: U_v \cap U_w \to G)_{v,w \in X_0}$ and we
could try to construct from this cocycle combinatorically
the classifying map $f_p: X \to BG$ which maps each vertex
to the unique vertex of $BG$, and every edge/ $1$-simplex
of $e_{vw} $ to the $1$-simplex of $BG$ determined by
$g_{vw} \in G$ from the cocycle. Note that the $1$-simplices of
$BG$ it Hatcher's bar construction correspond to elements of $G$.

Problems: Does such covering $(U_v)_{v \in X_0}$ with these
properties always exist for a Delta set $X$?
If yes, can this map I described on level of vertices and
$1$-simplices always be extended to the total Delta complex?

If $X$ would be a [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex)
then the answer should be yes because every $n$-simplex of
a simplicial complex is determinded by it's vertices, but
for Delta sets the glueing of boundaries could become
more complicated. For example several  vertices of same
$n$-simplex could be identified, for example a $1$-simplex
could become a circle when it's two vertices are identified.
Note that such glueings is allowed for Delta sets, but not for for
simplicial complexes.

On the other hand we can applying barycentric divisions to make a
Delta set $X$ to a simplicial complex. But this raises
another problem: Even if $X$ would be a simplicial complex,
the $BG$ is a Delta set (all $1$-simplices are circles)
and if we would resolve it with barycentric subdivisions to a
simplicial complex, it would not have this structure from
Hatcher's bar construction anymore, so it's $1$-simplices wouldn't
be identified with elements of $G$ anymore and we couldn't
associate $1$-simplices of $X$ to those of $BG$ using
cocycle representation of $p: P \to X$.

Could these issues be remedied and the classifying map
$f_p: X \to BG$ associated to $G$-bundle $p: P \to X$ over
base $X$ Delta set be described combinatorically in that or a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question uses semisimplicial sets, it makes sense to point out the following rather elegant model for the classifying space $\def\B{{\sf B}}\B G$ as a semisimplicial set: declare the set of $n$-simplices of $\B G$ to be the set of principal $G$-bundles over the $n$-simplex $Δ^n$ (the same $n$-simplex that is used in the construction of geometric realizations of semisimplicial sets).  The face maps restrict a principal $G$-bundle over $Δ^n$ to its faces.

Now given a semisimplicial set $K$ together with a principal $G$-bundle $P→|K|$, the classifying map $|K|→|\B G|$ is the geometric realization of the simplicial classifying map $K→\B G$ that sends an $n$-simplex $σ$ in $K$ to the restriction of the principal $G$-bundle $P→|K|$ to $|σ|⊂|K|$.

As usual, to ensure that $\B G$ is a simplicial set and not merely a simplicial class, any of the standard tricks can be deployed.  If the cardinality of $K$ is limited (the question talks specifically about finite $K$), then we can simply require the underlying sets of total spaces of principal $G$-bundles to be subsets of a fixed set, e.g., for a finite (or countable) $K$ we can take a set of cardinality continuum.

Concerning the question about using an open cover and its pairwise intersections to present a principal $G$-bundle, it is true at least in the contexts where good open covers are available, e.g., smooth manifolds.  This follows from Proposition 4.13 in [Numerable open covers and representability of topological stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.03120) and Lemma 3.3.28 in [Equivariant principal infinity-bundles](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.13654v3), which show that given an ∞-sheaf of groups on the site of cartesian spaces, its delooping as an ∞-presheaf is in fact an ∞-sheaf, so the descent datum for a principal $G$-bundle can be expressed as a morphism from the Čech nerve of a good open cover to the delooping $\B G$ as an ∞-presheaf (i.e., objectwise).

Comment: That's an interesting model, so to be sure, it's $n$-simplices 
$(\def\B{{\sf B}}\B G)_n$ are really 
literally formed by the set of principal $G$-bundles
over standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$ and not(!) the 
set of *isom classes* of prin $G$-bdles over $\Delta^n$
(which would be a singleton as $\Delta^n$ contractible).
In other words $(\def\B{{\sf B}}\B G)_n$ it distinguishes
between "as naked objects" different, but isomorphic 
prin $G$-bdles from each other or do you 
pose in $(\def\B{{\sf B}}\B G)_n$ some equivalence relation
(eg up to scaling) beeing weaker than isom relation?

Comment: Another point, pursuing the approach I sketched above from
 the "Here an approach..." part: Do you know if that works ...at 
least conceptually? So in certain sense if the "data" of a 
principal G-bundle $p:P \to X$ over a Delta set $X$ is only 
concentrated in the sense obove in dimension $1$ 
(ie from vertices & edges). And to construct the 
classifying map $f_p:X \to BG$ it suffice to determine it on 
$1$-skeleton level as a tried and then in this can 
(up to homotopy) it extends to $f_p$ whose pullback
 of universal bundle $EG \to BG$ is isom to to the origical $p$?

Comment: What "leads" me to this conjecture that this "could maybe" work:
Essentially the $BG$ for finite $G$ is a model for 
$1$-homotopy type, so it reasonable to expect that the neccessary data 
for construction of classifiyng map associated to 
principal $G$-bundle $p:P \to X$ over $X$ "simple enough" -
here a finite Delta set - lying in $1$-skeleton might be enough to fully construct 
$f_p: X \to BG$, or is my intuition misleading me at that point?

Comment: @JackYo: There is no equivalence relation used in the construction.  I also added a paragraph about the other approach, where the answer is positive at least in some cases.

Comment: Thank you. I have to admit that I'm far from beeing familar
with language of higher algebra, so maybe this question
becomes nearly trivial: In your paper Prop 4.13 states 
that when a sheaf $G$ of groups on the site Cart, it is  
objectwise delooping  $(M \to 
BG(M))$ - where I assume that there you use the term "objectwise"
at that stage to ephasise that you consider it a priori as a presheaf -  satisfies the homotopy descent property.

Comment: If we now bulk up our objects to $\infty$-(pre)sheaves, do 
I understand it correctly that for a $\infty$-presheaf 
to be a sheaf is *by definition* equivalent to satisfy this 
"homotopy descent property" 
(https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Brown-Gersten+property#OverSmoothmanifolds)
where essentially lim is weakened to holim?

Comment: Furthermore, the last part I not completely understand: When we now know that the
delooping $\infty$-presheaf is a actually a $\infty$-sheaf, why
this implies that a descent datum for a principal $G$-bundle
can be expressed as a morphism 
the Čech nerve of a good open cover to the delooping 
$BG$ as $\infty$-presheaf? 
Keeping this on more elementary level presheaf being sheaf means 
just that descent is effective. But how this "translates" to 
the last quoted statement with morphism from Cech nerve 
to $BG$?

Comment: @JackYo: Yes, that's correct.  The groupoid of principal G-bundles over X is the dervied mapping space (or groupoid) RMap(X,BG).  RMap can be computed as the right derived functor of Map (the simplicial mapping space), by cofibrantly replacing X and fibrantly replacing BG.  If BG is an ∞-sheaf, then BG is fibrant in the local projective model structure on simplicial presheaves.  A cofibrant resolution of X is given by the Čech nerve of a good open cover of X.  Altogether, we get the groupoid of maps from the Čech nerve to BG.  Thus, Čech cohomology computes sheaf cohomology in this context.

Comment: One little nitpick, you suggested in the brackets that the dervied mapping space $\text{RMap}(X,BG)$ carries naturally even a structure of a groupoid. Do I understand it correctly that in this framework your all "spaces" are considered automatically as "groupoids", so even when we start naively from a priori "just a space" - like $\text{RMap}(X,BG)$ - you implicitly treat it in this context as a groupoid due to some natural embedding "in the background" of these "spaces" in the bigger category of groupoids, right? In other words in spirit of the slogan "spaces are groupoids"?

Comment: @JackYo: Spaces could be taken to mean simplicial sets here.  Groupoids embed into simplicial sets via the nerve functor.  BG is a presheaf of groupoids (and therefore simplicial sets) on the site of cartesian spaces.  (The space BG used in the first two paragraphs of my answer is not the same BG, but rather the shape of the presheaf BG.)  Thus, the derived mapping object from X to BG is itself naturally a groupoid, the groupoid of principal G-bundles over X.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by that the simplicial set 
you constructed in  first two paragraphs - a model 
of classifying space, let 
call it $BG^S$ in order distinguish it from "the other, say "canonical" presheaf $BG$"
 - is rather the shape of the the latter $BG$?

I assume that the way you are going to use it next, is 
that generally a derived mapping object with target beeing 
a groupoid carries naturally groupoid structure, so 
$\text{RMap}(X,BG)$ would have groupoid structure "for free"
for $BG$ the "canonical" presheaf of groupoids,

Comment: but because of this
remark that $BG^S$ has rather the shape of the presheaf $BG$, 
$\text{RMap}(X,BG^S)$ inherits groupoid structure, so a kind
of replacement argument. That's
the argument you use there, right? But could you lose
some words what you formally precisely mean by that 
"$BG^S$ has rather the shape of the presheaf $BG$"? It that a kind of "higher homotopy equivalence" allowing replacements preserving properties, as eg here for "beeing groupoid"?

Comment: @JackYo: Maps into BG^S and BG classify different things.  The derived space of maps of spaces X→BG^S is equivalent to the ∞-groupoid of principal G-bundles over X, their concordances, and higher concordances (parametrized by the simplex Δ^k) as k-morphisms.  The derived space of maps RMap(X,BG) of ∞-sheaves (and not just spaces) X→BG is equivalent to the groupoid of principal G-bundles over X and their isomorphisms.  Finally, the ∞-groupoid RMap(X,BG^S) is equivalent to the shape of the derived internal hom RHom(X,BG), whereas RMap(X,BG) is equivalent to RHom(X,BG)(R^0).

Comment: Could you make precise what you mean in this context that object $A$ "is shape of" object $B$ (as you remarked in previous comment on relation between $BG^S$ and presheaf $BG$)? Similarly, that something is equivalent "to the shape" of another object? Does the term "shape" in this context have a precise meaning?

Comment: @JackYo: Some formulas and definitions for the shape functor can be found here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+via+cohesive+path+∞-groupoid